# How can I refresh a .properties file mid program?

Tags: java

I have a program that will write to a `config.properties` file with information that is shown in a separate `.java` form that is shown once you press a button.

The code to write that I current have is:

```
finally {
                prop.setProperty("row0", textToWrite.replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "."));              
            }
// save properties to project root folder
            prop.store(output, null);
```

Although once you set it, you need to close the program to see the change in the `.properties` file and therefore on the table inside the program.

I've tried searching for code that will `refresh` the file although with no luck.

**EDIT:**

As asked, a simple example would be this:

Properties file at the start:

```
Row0=Item1&&Item123;
Row1=Item2&&Item234;
Row2=Item3&&Item345;
```

The program will edit these so it should turn out like this:

```
Row0=NewItem&&NewItem2;
Row1=Item1&&Item123;
Row2=Item2&&Item234;
```

Although it only updates the file after the program is closed.

I am writing to a .properties file because it is a small amount of information that will be able to be read/edited without too much effort.

Comment: What do you mean by having to close the program to see the change? Please elaborate, clarify, show code. Preferably a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And out of curiosity, why use properties for this?

Comment: Please show the code you use to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the cause of your problem is that you read properties file only at the start of your application. As you are changing the property file through code and want the other part of the code to see the properties change, so you need to introduce a properties file reload logic.

One way to do this is to move your properties file read logic in a separate method and call this method every time you make a change to the property file.

Other way could be using listeners, observers, etc.